# Neither Alex nor Ali can achieve his/her dream Vs Neither Alex nor Ali can achieve them dream

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, american-english

Which is the correct one of these two examples? I tried to say no one of them can achieve his or her own dream.

1. Neither Alex nor Ali can achieve his/her dream
2. Neither Alex nor Ali can achieve them dream

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Which do you think is correct, and why? What references have you tried? This question might get the correct attention at our sister site, https://ell.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: _Them dream_ is wrong in any context. When speaking of more than one person, possibly of different sexes, you can say _their dream_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither Alex nor Ali can achieve their dream. 
If they are unsuccessfully pursuing a dream put forward by one of them it matters which: John dreams of being able to fly. Neither Alex nor Ali can achieve his dream.

Answer (score -1):

I would say,

Neither Alex nor Ali can achieve her dream.

The pronoun will refer to the subject closest to it. In this case, pronoun refers to Ali.

Comment: Please explain why. It would be helpful to the OP and to future visitors if you could explain the error(s), if any, in the OP's examples.

Comment: The feminine possessive pronoun is *her* but how do we know that Alex or Ali 
 is a female? The name Alex is ambiguous, it could be short for Alexander or Alexandra.

Comment: I assume that Alex is male while Ali is female. (Because the OP said his/her, respectively).

Comment: Since Ali is a female, I would use "her". Do you think it's correct?

Comment: But by using only "her", in your solution,  the listener will presume that Alex and Ali are females.

Comment: I preferred your first solution, the singular  "their", but you should explain why.

Comment: No Ali is a male in Arabic language.